# Blank screen after ATI radeon RX 550 update

Tags: updates, screen, radeon

I recently update Ubuntu and after a restart the screen is totally black.

I think it might have to do with my Radeon RX550 as it asked me something about the drivers  before starting.

I tried the live usb in try ubuntu mode and run the boot repair tool but nothing happened.

any advice?

thanks

UPDATE
from the logs I am getting
snd_hda_intel hsw/bdw hd-audio hdmi/dp requires binding with gfx driver

Comment: Update from what version of Ubuntu to what version of Ubuntu or just updates to the version in use. Please be clear.

Comment: the current Ubuntu version is 22.04.02 LTS

Comment: Not what I asked.

Comment: I really dont know what was the previous version. but from what I remember I tried to install manually the NVIDIA RX550 drivers. Before restarting it asked me if I want to keep the old drivers and I replied NO.

Answer (score 0):

By pressing ESC after BIOS check I went to advanced options in GRUB menu then Kernel recovery mode and then root.

typed
amdgpu-uninstall

to remove the drivers

thanks for your help.